# using a loop to change an image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi im fairly new at javascript and i got an error in my script yet i cant find the bug what im trying to do is put all my images in an array then loop the array using a forloop just iike in java.Then set and interval to change the source of the image using iteration.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){

        SetInterval(function(){

            var images = ["graphic1.jpg" , "graphic2.jpg" , "graphic3.jpg" , "graphic4.jpg" , "graphic5.jpg"];

            for(i=0;i<images.length;i++){
                $("#slide").attr("src", images[i]);
            } 
        } , 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: setInterval ... note lower case s

Comment: "i got an error" - clearly this happens in the console ... which clearly states what the error actually is

Comment: Take a few minutes to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve then re-frame your question.

Answer (score 1):

1) It is `setInterval` not `SetInterval`

2) Use either `document.ready()` or `function()`

Answer (score 0):

First off you have 2 'document.ready' functions. Try the following:

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        var images = ["graphic1.jpg" , "graphic2.jpg" , "graphic3.jpg" , "graphic4.jpg" , "graphic5.jpg"];

        for(i=0;i<images.length;i++){
            $("#slide").attr("src", images[i]);
        } 
    } , 1000);
});
```

Comment: @Muhsin When you reach the required reputation, please accept this answer